# Error messages and having better organized code in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oop

When it starts it loads data from a file and verify if it is correct before saving it in memory.

```
RepositoryInFile::RepositoryInFile(Validator *validator){
    this->validator = validator;
    this->read();
}
```

read() is a private method that tries to open and read data from a file. It also throws exceptions. When I catch an error in my program I do something like this:

```
  try {
    //do something
  } catch (CustomException customE) {
    QString message = QString::fromStdString(customE.reason());
    // I'm not extending std::exception beacause... well I don't know why
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error!", message);
  }
```

Now, if something goes wrong in RepositoryInFile's constructor I can throw a exception and I can catch it in my main function, but I can't show a nice message box on screen informing the user that something went wrong (OR I don't know how). 
Right now I show a message in console with qDebug(), but that has only the purpose to help me.

Comment: The last paragraph sounds very good. First start the GUI, then start doing the rest in a separate thread and notify the GUI about any updates.

Comment: "... but I can't show a nice message box on screen". Why you cannot?

Comment: @vahancho because QMessageBox::critical ( QWidget * parent, const QString & title, const QString & text, StandardButtons buttons = Ok, StandardButton defaultButton = NoButton ) and the same goes for QMessageBox::information and QMessageBox::warning. What is the parent when I'm in main? I'm new to this Qt thing, that's why I said "or I don't know how".

Comment: @user3002428, if you have no other windows in your application, you can set the parent argument to be null (0).

Comment: @vahancho oh, thanks! But is it ok to have my code organized like that? With read() called in constructor?

Comment: @user3002428, actually, no, if the `read()` function throws exceptions - you better avoid doing that in constructors. You might let your object fully constructed before reading anything and throw exceptions.

Comment: @vahancho in this case I'm going to rewrite some parts to avoid that. Thnaks again :)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I redesign the way my RepositoryInFile works and have some other method that will load data from the file after the GUI is initialized?

Not necessarily needed. You could simply show the message box in the exception handler. The only change that you would need to make is this:

```
QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error!", message);
//                    ^
```

So, basically if you replace this with "zero" then it will become the "root" of your UI.